# MySQL INSERT INTO SELECT from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I'm working on the following query:

```
SELECT app_downloads.APP_ID, FONT_ID
FROM `app_downloads`,`fonts`
GROUP BY app_downloads.APP_ID
ORDER BY SUM(DOWNLOADS) DESC
LIMIT 0,20
```

The result is:

```
APP_ID |FONT_ID     
4543   |11
4689   |11
1268   |11
```

I'd like to associate to every APP_ID a different FONT_ID from table 'fonts'

```
FONT_ID |NAME   
11      |FONT1
12      |FONT2....
```

Do you have any idea how to solve it in a single query?

Thank you,
Elena

Comment: Is there any relation between `app_downloads` and `fonts`? Do you want to bring them together them randomly?

Comment: Where is the insert?  Could you clarify what you mean by a different font_id?  Do you mean you want every possible combination of app_id and font_id in the results?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't have support to multitable insert in a Single Query.

If you are worried about the integrity of the data, you can use Transactions to assure you that your two queries and their values will be correctly added in your database.

MySQL Transaction: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html